# Blog Search and Comment Form Not Working in Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento

After I installed the FishPig Wordpress extension in a Magento site the blog search and comment form are not working.  Can anyone show me how to store comments on a post in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of the extension and if the error persists, contact FishPig support directly at help@fishpig.co.uk